# How to get current length of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput while recording to display on screen?

Tags: swift, video, time, avfoundation, recording

As title says, I am looking to display the current length of the recording while a user is recording video with AVFoundation. I have done something similar with AVAudioRecorder where I create a timer that sets a label's text as follows:

`recordDurationLabel.text =  timeString((audioRecorder?.currentTime)!)`

I was wondering if there is a "currentTime" feature for recording video? My only other thought would be to start a repeated 1 second timer in the captureOutput:didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL function but I want to ensure accuracy.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
For now this is the function I've implemented in the captureOutput:didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL delegate method, but again, would be cleaner to have something directly related to the video.

```
func startRecordingUpdateTimer() {

    recordingUpdateTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0/45.0, target: self, selector: #selector(recordedVideo), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(recordingUpdateTimer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func recordedVideo() {
    durationTime = durationTime + 1.0/45.0
    let durationString = timeString(durationTime)
    recordDurationLabel.text =  durationString
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, you can get the duration of the movie by using `recordedDuration` which is read only and will return you a CMTime when the recording has started. See [AVCaptureFileOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureFileOutput/recordedDuration).

If you use `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` you'll receive `CMSampleBuffer`objects which contain a `CMTime`that you can access with `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp`.

Doing a CMTime operation like `CMTimeSubstract` will allow you to calculate the time difference between the current buffer and the first one you recorded.

If you have never manipulated sampleBuffers, you should take a look at this example code from Apple: [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid AVCaptureVideoDataOutput but seems like this is going to be the way to do it then.

Comment: My bad, I rarely use the MovieFileOutput. I checked the documentation, simply keep a reference to your output, and access the duration with `recordedDuration`. Edited the answer